# Вопрос по сериализации и десериализации System.Linq.Expressions.Expression c#

Tags: c#, expressions

Решил потестить `Serialize.Linq;` стало интересно как в c# можно сохранить сереализованное дерево выражения и отработать на массиве объектов. Сделал пример ниже, но не могу понять как все это работает.

Почему в 1 случае `cond.Compile()` сработает в `Where`, а `cond2.Compile()` при выполнении выбрасывает `System.InvalidOperationException`: *"На переменную "x" типа "ConsoleApp1.User" имеется ссылка из области "", но она не определена"*.

Как сделать так, чтобы после десериализации тоже все работало?

при `expr1.ToString()` печатается ровно такая же структура, что и у `actualExpression.ToString()`
actualExpression  после дес-ции имеет тип System.Linq.Expressions.Expression

```
List<User> list = new List<User>() {
    new User() { Name = "Витя" },
    new User() { Name = "Катя" },
    new User() { Name = "Лена" }
};

var pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User),"x");
var expr1 = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(pe,"Name"), Expression.Constant("Катя"));
var cond = Expression.Lambda<Func<User, bool>>(expr1,pe); 

var serializer = new ExpressionSerializer(new JsonSerializer());
string value = serializer.SerializeText(cond.Body);
Console.WriteLine("value:" + value);

//// Deserialize expression
var actualExpression = serializer.DeserializeText(value);
Console.WriteLine(actualExpression.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("actualExpression:" + actualExpression.ToJson());

var cond2=Expression.Lambda<Func<User, bool>>(actualExpression, cond.Parameters); 
list.Where(cond.Compile()).Select(c => { Console.WriteLine(c.Name); return c; }).ToList();
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101351/discussion-between-grundy-and-mikevan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это происходит из-за того, что у вас после десериализации создается новый объект параметра `x` (т.е. переменная `x` созданная в `cond1` не равна той, что была создана при десереализации в `cond2`). Это можно исправить сериализируя и десериализируя полное lambda выражение:

```
// тут будет сохранено полное выражение, которое уже имеет нужный параметр
var value = serializer.SerializeText(cond);

// тут оно будет восстановлено обратно
var actualExpression = serializer.DeserializeText(value) as Expression<Func<User, bool>>;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое))